# Extract transform load project incremental load

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert only updated data for my ETL project, it's working. But I have one problem which in the latter I will showcase. I have this `etl_watermark` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dwreporting.etl_watermark 
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    last_update_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1800-01-01 00:00:00',
    table_name varchar(255)
   

);
 ALTER TABLE dwreporting.etl_watermark
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_table_name UNIQUE (table_name);
```

and since I have a timestamp I am converting the values of my google sheet to make it match.

I have values in my sheets as a integer such as `2023` and other `last_update` columns with values like `12/2/2023`.

Here is the function to create staging table and insert updated data:

```
def create_table_and_insert_data(db_session, df, sheet_name, config_path='config.json'):
    if df is not None:
        schema_name = "dwreporting"
        table_name = sheet_name.lower()
        watermark_table_name = "etl_watermark"

        # Load configuration from config.json
        with open(config_path, 'r') as config_file:
            config = json.load(config_file)

        # Get timestamp column for the current sheet from config
        timestamp_column_name = config['staging_tables'][table_name]['timestamp_column']

        # Convert the 'timestamp_column' in the DataFrame to datetime
        df[timestamp_column_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[timestamp_column_name], errors='coerce')

        # Create or update the staging table
        full_table_name, create_statement = data_handler.return_create_statement_from_df(df, schema_name, table_name, "stg", config_path=config_path)
        database_handler.execute_query(db_session, create_statement)

        # Retrieve last update timestamp from etl_watermark table
        last_update_query = f"""
            SELECT last_update_timestamp FROM {schema_name}.{watermark_table_name}
            WHERE table_name = '{full_table_name}';
        """
        last_update_result = database_handler.execute_query_and_fetch(db_session, last_update_query)

        if last_update_result:
            timestamp_object = last_update_result[0][0]

            # Convert the timestamp to a datetime object if it's an integer
            formatted_timestamp = timestamp_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            print(f"Last Update Timestamp: {formatted_timestamp}")
        else:
            print("No results returned.")
            timestamp_object = None

        if timestamp_object is not None:
            new_or_updated_records = df[df[timestamp_column_name] > timestamp_object]

            if not new_or_updated_records.empty:
                # Insert new or updated records into the staging table
                insert_statements = data_handler.return_insert_statement_from_df(new_or_updated_records, schema_name, full_table_name, db_session)
                for insert_statement in insert_statements:
                    database_handler.execute_query(db_session, insert_statement)

                # Update the last update timestamp in the etl_watermark table
                update_watermark_query = f"""
                    INSERT INTO {schema_name}.{watermark_table_name} (last_update_timestamp, table_name)
                    VALUES ('{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}', '{full_table_name}')
                    ON CONFLICT (table_name)
                    DO UPDATE SET last_update_timestamp = EXCLUDED.last_update_timestamp;
                """
                database_handler.execute_query(db_session, update_watermark_query)
            else:
                print("No new or updated records found.")
        else:
            regular_records = df

            # Insert regular records into the staging table
            insert_statements = data_handler.return_insert_statement_from_df(regular_records, schema_name, full_table_name, db_session)
            for insert_statement in insert_statements:
                database_handler.execute_query(db_session, insert_statement)

            # Update the last update timestamp in the etl_watermark table
            update_watermark_query = f"""
                INSERT INTO {schema_name}.{watermark_table_name} (last_update_timestamp, table_name)
                VALUES ('{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}', '{full_table_name}')
                ON CONFLICT (table_name)
                DO UPDATE SET last_update_timestamp = EXCLUDED.last_update_timestamp;
            """
            database_handler.execute_query(db_session, update_watermark_query)
```

This works if I run twice it will not insert same data but my problem is for example

```
Entity  Code    Year
Afghanistan AFG 2001
Afghanistan AFG 2002
```

When I insert these:

```
1   "Afghanistan"   "AFG"   "2001-01-01 00:00:00"
2   "Afghanistan"   "AFG"   "2002-01-01 00:00:00"
3   "Afghanistan"   "AFG"   "2003-01-01 00:00:00"
```

Here the year is timestamp.
How can I keep the data of the sheet? I need it to be inserted to the database, whether in integer or `/` format.

Comment: Insert into what? Some flavor of SQL database?